# Is it worth experimenting with different heap allocators on Linux for multi core servers for nginx or haproxy

Tags: c++, c, nginx, multicore, hoard

I am doing some experiments to find out the ceiling of my requests per second rate of haproxy and nginx on RHEL or Centos.

Part of my setup in nginx uses embedded LUA in the form of LuaJIT. My question is this:

Does anybody have any experience or advice about the usefulness of doing some testing of these apps after building with alternative heap allocators such as [Hoard](http://www.hoard.org/) or [Lockless](http://locklessinc.com/products/allocdl.shtml).

Any thoughts gratefully received.
Dave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experiments at a previous employer showed that the standard Linux and Solaris malloc/free implementations were not particularly efficient in high-concurrency multicore environments. We realized significant performance improvements by creating a custom allocator. I think it is definitely worthwhile to do experiments with alternative allocators. If you are still working on this project, please post your findings!

Note that this was for a web service written in C. I have no experience with nginx, Hoard, or Lockless.